# How to show a language is not recursive, without using reductions?

Tags: complexity-theory, formal-languages, automata, undecidability, recursively-enumerable

I would like to show a language is in not recursive (not in the family $R$) without using a reduction from a language that is known to be non-recursive. In other words, its as if I am discovering the first non-recursive language.

I have 2 languages I would like to show it for. These are:

1. $L_{AC}$ - the pairs $\left<M,w\right>$ such that $M$ accepts $w$.
2. $L_{HL}$ - the pairs $\left<M,w\right>$ such that $M$ halts on $w$ (doesn't go into a non-ending loop).

Its obvious both are in $RE$, simply simulate them by using a universal TM. But apart from a logical argument, I'm not sure how to approach this, considering I do not allow reductions (more as, I am trying to discover the first language or two in $R$, so its as if I don't have any previous knowledge on $R$).

Comment: Are you familiar with the usual proof that the halting problem is not recursive? Try replicating it.

Comment: Hi, actually I am not. Do you have a source?

Comment: There are many sources on the web, including [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem#Sketch_of_rigorous_proof).